# MVC Call Controller/Method from Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in my MVC View:

```
    <a href='@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")'> Email </a>
```

Below, SupportNeeded is the Controller and EmailPerson in the method

What is the equivalent if I do it in Jquery. Obviously I do not need the Email Lable.
I just want it to automatically go to EmailPerson Method in SupportNeeded controller.

Note that I have EmailPerson and EmailPerson with HttpPost in my controller.

I tried in my Jquery

```
    '@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")'
```

but that didn't do anything for me.
I also tried the .post :

```
    var url = '@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")';
    $.post(url), function (data) { });
```

but it went to the Method that has  [HttpPost]. I need it to go to the method that does not have  [HttpPost]. I then tried .get but did not do anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using regular JavaScript.

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you need. If you want to use `$.get` which will perform an ajax request, this works:

```
$.get("@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")");
```

If you're trying to redirect to that action you can do:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("EmailPerson", "SupportNeeded")";
```